# change the module value in tsconfig.json automatically

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, frontend

I have an express server in react app with typescript. When i run `npm run dev` the server works fine, but when I run `npm start` in another session in the terminal the module in `tsconfig.json` changes automatically from `commonJS` to `esnext`. The server was turned off because the module was changed.  Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Here how the module was changed from `commonJS` to `esnext` when I run `npm start` in `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
--> "module": "commonJS",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "strict": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
--> "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "strict": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that I want to use react app  and express server with typescript. so if we want to do that we should separate between the client side and the server side. and I didn't do that when I asked the question.
and [this article](https://medium.com/codeduck/a-real-world-project-typescript-express-and-react-4701c0458e9c) in medium explain this in details.

hope this is clear!!